# How to add background to textview

Tags: android, background, textview

How to add background to textview (png with white cloud) that the background will stretch depending of text length.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should really work to increase your accept rate. You are far more likely to get the kind of help you want on StackOverflow if you a decent accept rate. At the very least you want to get yourself above 0%. [Check out the FAQ for some nice pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

In the meantime [check out an overview of 9-patch graphics here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

You can use them to create the effect you are after. The image will grow in the regions that you specify to fill up all the space that the content takes up.

Inside your xml you can set it to a TextView with;

```
android:background="@drawable/yourimagename"
```

and just replace yourimagename, with the name of the resulting png file that you put in the drawables folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the image as a resource to your res/drawable folder (I recommend providing resolution-specific versions on res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, etc). Then, you can set the TextView's background by setting the android:background property to something like "@drawable/clouds".

However, I really recommend that you think about your application's design as a whole before applying backgrounds to specific components. Think about what your application will look like as a whole. Adding complex graphics as a background to text individual components may not be aesthetically pleasant.

A very good read on Android interface design:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: I dont even think to add background as a backgrounto the text, it can be ImageView, but how to fit to textview? To be always the same width na height as textview? thanks